# Abelian ideals of $\mathfrak{n}_+$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras

Let $g$ be a finite dimensional simple Lie algebra. Then we have the root space decomposition
$$
g=\mathfrak{h}\oplus \mathfrak{n}_+ \oplus \mathfrak{n}_-.
$$
My question: how to classify the abelian ideals of $\mathfrak{n}_+$ that are closed under $\mathfrak h$-action?

Comment: This can be translated into a combinatorial problem as follows. Being $\mathfrak{h}$-submodules, these are graded submodules of $\mathfrak{n}_+$, hence given by a subset $F$ of the set of positive roots $\Phi_+$ (in particular, there are finitely many). The condition of being abelian means that $x+y\notin\Phi_+$ for all $x,y\in F$. The condition of being an ideal of $\mathfrak{n}_+$ means that if $x\in\Phi_+$ and $y\in F$ and $x+y\in\Phi_+$ then $x+y\in F$.

Comment: (I assumed a split semisimple Lie algebra in char 0, e.g., complex simple)